# How can I merge two ASCII characters?

Tags: c, binary, char, ascii, bit

I want to merge two characters and print them via a single variable by using ASCII (refer to the image below):

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWodP.jpg[image][image]

Comment: A union of a monolithic wide enough integer and a struct of two chars could be what you want. But that is not considered clean. Did you consider casting to int, shifting and bit-ORing?

Comment: Note that the value of `C` after the initialization `int C = 'AB';` is [implementation-defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10).

Comment: Try `int C; C= (((int)a)<<8)|((int)b);` If that works and gets you what you want I make an answer and explain.

Comment: The casts should be to `(unsigned char)A` to avoid sign-extension problems when plain `char` is a signed type and the values in the variables are negative.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not sure I can follow you. I would not trust an unsigned char to hold a value which was left-shifted by 8.

Comment: @yunnosch Can you please explain this logic  ```C= (((int)a)<<8)|((int)b);```

Comment: If it gets you what you need I will, in an answer. If it does not, let me know how it fails, so that I can adapt and improve.

Comment: @Yunnosch: If you have `(unsigned char)A << 8` as a term, then the `unsigned char` value is extended to `int` before the shift occurs, and the result is an `int`, and the value in `A` will not have been sign-extended even if the plain `char` type is a signed type and the value in `A` is a negative `char` value.  If you convert a negative, (implicitly signed) `char` value direct to `int`, then it will be sign-extended, and the upper bits of the result will all be 1 bits.

Comment: Yes! This approach seems legit. @yunnosch

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not see negative values being relevant here, but I agree that you can never be too safe. Are you going to make an answer? Or can I create the one I had in mind, improved by your input?

Comment: @Yunnosch — I don't plan to answer.  Please create your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if your machine is little endian

```
unsigned int C = (b << 8) | a;
printf("%s",&C);
```

otherwise if your machine is big endian try

```
unsigned int C = (a << 24) | (b<<16);
printf("%s",&C);
```

Comment: 1st one working fine! Can you please explain your code I'm new and im aware of bitshift

Comment: bytes are ordered in memory by a concept of endianess which is of two types (i)little and (ii) big. so for ex: 0x12345678 is an 8 byte number stored at address 0x100. Normally you'd think that 0x12 is stored at 0x100 , 0x34 at 0x101 ... that is done in big endian machines which are mostly sun machines. coming to little endian machines 0x78 is stored at 0x100, 0x56 is at 0x101, 0x34 at 0x102 and 0x12 at 0x103 so the bytes are reversed in little endian machines.

Comment: so C = (b << 8) | a in case of little endian machines is stored at &C as 0x41420000 which can be read as a null terminated string.

Comment: Mismatched arguments and conversion specifiers cause undefined behavior in C. `%s` expects a pointer to a character type, but `&C` is a pointer to `unsigned int`, hence undefined behavior. This solution is fragile, at best.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment, but improved by Jonathan's input, I propose to do this:

```
int C;
C= (((unsigned char)a)<<8)|((unsigned char)b);
```

You have already tried the commented version to be helpful, this one is basically the same, just being robust against potentially negative values of `a` and `b` (which I considered out of scope, but Jonathan is right in being as safe as possible).

As for the explanation:

The `<< 8` part, a so-called bitshift left, moves a value by 8 bit towards the MSBs.
I.e. a `00000000010000001` becomes a `01000000100000000`.

To be safe from negative value (see below why that is important), the value is first type-casted to `unsigned char`. That is the part `((unsigned char)a)`. Note that I tend to be generous when it comes to using `()`, some people do not like that. This is done for both values.

With values `'A'` and `'B'` we end up with

`0100000100000000` and
`0000000001000010`.

The next part uses a bitwise OR (`|`), in contrast to a logical OR (`||`).
The result is

`0100000101000010`, which is what I understand to be your goal.

The importance of protecting against negative input is this. Any negative 8bit value has the MSB set and when cast to a wider data type will end up with all 8 new high bits set. This is because of the representation of negative values in integers in 2-compliment.

The final conversion to the desired wider data type is as Jonathan explains:

If you have `(unsigned char)A << 8` as a term, then the unsigned char value is extended to int before the shift occurs, and the result is an int.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Since I do not want to misrepresent you, I invite you to point out anything you do not like.